# Jelly bean upgrading Problems

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s, updates, 4.2-jelly-bean

My new *Samsung Galaxy Advance S* is running with android Gingerbread. I am thinking to upgrade it to Jelly Bean. I am very new to Android devices.

I have following basic questions

1. Are there any known advantages and disadvantages in upgrading my device to JellyBean?
2. If I upgrade to Jelly Bean do my all apps remain works?
3. Upgrading OS, does it void my warranty?
4. Is there any official instruction to upgrade my phone to Jelly Bean?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Existing questions with answers you might want to consult: [How do I update the OS on my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/16575) / [Will factory resetting my device remove the Android upgrade?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12626/16575) / [How can I make Android remember default apps after upgrades?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19968/16575)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are many advantages. Your phone's usable RAM memory increases from 555MB to 625MB.
Camera zoom is possible, but only digital zoom is available. So it's of no use.
All your old apps will work fine in JB, but games will lag unless you root your phone.

Upgrading to Jelly Bean if you are in India will void warranty.

There are no official instructions to update. You will have to do it manually. If you are new to Android, get help from someone who has Android knowledge. Otherwise, you may end up bricking your phone.

I would suggest you don't upgrade, because JB update for S Advance will be available in India soon.